# Is there any way to convert to swift code to objective-c on Mac?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have 100+ lines of code of swift programming. But I want to appropriate code in other language like objective -c .
Is there any way to convert this code to other language directly ?

Comment: 100+ lines of code isn't that much, even if a tool existed it would probably be faster and yield a better result to translate it manually than to learn that tool, use it and verify the result.

Comment: Why would you ever want to convert Swift code to Obj-C? You can call Swift code from Obj-C and Obj-C is an inferior language to Swift, so really, there's no reason to ever want to do the conversion that way.

Comment: @DávidPásztor - nice, which version of Swift are you referring to?

Comment: All versions :) Swift had Obj-C interoperability from its release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such tools for converting Swift code to Objective-C. There are some reasons. One is because Objective-C is a semantic subset of Swift, i. e. Objective-C doesn't have any equivalent of some fundamental features of Swift such as Generics, Algebraic data types, Pattern matching and other.